# Finding an analog switch IC (BBM & SPDT) for video signal

Tags: switches, analog, integrated-circuit, video, spdt

I'm looking for a SPDT analog switch IC with Break-before-make to switch between video signals. However, the amount of options available leaves me overwhelmed with no clear option in sight.

I've found this [PDF](https://www.ti.com/lit/sg/slyb125d/slyb125d.pdf) from TI and a switch like [TS3A44159](https://www.ti.com/product/TS3A44159) seems to fill my requirements, with the caveat of being surface mount (I'd prefer to have through-hole to tinker more easily, but it's not a strict requirement).

Would an IC like that be a good option for video signals like HDMI/DP? Is there a better way or a better place to look for components like these? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The crosstalk, even in a 50 ohm system, may be too high for a SPDT in one IC. I suggest you implement "T" switches: two SPST in series, with the center_node either "shorted to Ground" or floating.